# How to solve: This URL is already in use by another Google service (Sites Google)?

Tags: plesk, google-sites

I have just verified the custom URL for my Sites Google. When I want to assign it, it says, "This URL is already in use by another Google service." Meanwhile, I don't remember using the URL for any Google service. I just verified it with Google Webmasters. Anyway, I use Plesk for my domain services. Any help?

This is my site: https://sites.google.com/view/alvisyhrn/home
This is my URL: www.alvisyahrin.com

Your help will be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I use Google Domains but was running into the same error message. [This post](https://medium.com/google-cloud-platform-by-cloud-ace/this-url-is-already-in-use-by-another-google-service-google-sites-error-7d355a325ee5) suggests creating and then deleting a synthetic redirect record (e.g. `www.alvisyahrin.com` -> `http://google.com`) in Google Domains. This displayed a "All resource records in this synthetic record will be deleted." message before deleting, and seems to have done the trick, since as soon as I deleted the synthetic record Sites was willing to use it as a custom domain.

I realize you're using a different registrar for your domain, but visiting your site now it looks like you managed to get things working (I assume by doing something like this). Hopefully this will be a helpful breadcrumb for Google Domains users that run into this, at least.